# Unable to connect to a specific ftp server from ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ftp

I have -

1) A FTP server hosted on a rackspace machine

2) An AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu) - wanting to be a client

Problem -
When I try to ftp-connect to the server - **I get an error (almost instantly) - ftp: connect: No route to host**

Notes -

1) I can ping the server from the client (so the IP is reachable)

2) The client is able to ftp-connect to some other ftp servers

3) I am able to ftp-connect to the server from my personal laptop

Comment: Do you use the ip or a symbolic name in the ftp command within AWS?

Comment: Tried both. ping works but ftp doesn't